# Dynamic String array dosent work

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays, calloc

I'm trying to create a dynamic array of 1000 character long strings using calloc:

```
int i;
char** strarr =(char**)calloc(argc,sizeof(char)*1000);
if(strarr == NULL)
    return 0;
strarr[0][0] ='a';
printf("%c\n",strarr[0][0]);
```

Every time i try to run this code i get segmentation fault on the printf line, i don't get why does this happen (you can assume that argc is bigger than 0)
Thanks

P.s. im sorry that the code is in text format but im using a mobile so i dont have the code feature

Comment: `strarr[0]` is a null pointer. `strarr[0][0]` is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const int num_of_strings = 255; //argc ?
const int num_of_chars = 1000;

int i;
char** strarr =(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*num_of_strings);

if(strarr == NULL)
    return 0;
for (i = 0; i < num_of_strings; i++) strarr[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*num_of_chars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and Welcome to the world of undefined behaviour, one of the darkest territories of the C language. Your code has several problems, which cause undefined behaviour in several occasions, but they all get executed, until you reach the `printf` line, where you are accessing memory, you have not allocated, which is finally caught by your system and, thus, a segmentation fault is produced.

But I think, it would be better to walk ourselves through your code.

1. The variable i, which is declared in the `int i;` line is not used anywhere in the code you have posted, but I guess you need it later.
2. The first piece of code, that is not right, is in this second line, where you declare an array of strings or a `char**`. That means that you have a pointer to pointers to chars. So, what you really want to do there is allocate memory for those pointers and not for the chars they will point to. Note that a `char` consumes a different amount of memory than a `char*`. This line is, thus, the one to go with.

   ```
   char** strarr = (char**) calloc(argc, sizeof(char*));
   ```

   This will allocate memory for argc blocks of memory, each of which is of size 4 or 8 bytes, which depends on whether your system is 32 or 64-bit.
3. You are doing a very good job of checking whether the `calloc` function returned NULL or not, which is a very good practice overall.
4. Next, you will want to allocate memory for the strings themselves, that are pointed to by the pointers, for which you allocated memory in the previous line. These lines will do it.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
       strarr[i] = (char*) calloc(1000, sizeof(char));
   }
   ```

   This will now allocate 1000-character lengthed strings for every element of our argc-sized string array.

After that, you can continue with your code as it is and I think that no errors will be produced. Please accept an additional piece of advice from me. Learn to love valgrind. It is a very helpful program, which you can run your code with, in order to analyse memory. It is my first step, whenever I get a segmentation fault.